# How to set different background depending on hotspot hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would like to modify this codepen https://codepen.io/varcharles/pen/qNQpRv
When hovering a red dot the box on right should change is background related on which hotspot is selected. So, four different images related to 4 different hotspots.

```
const dataField = document.querySelector('.data');

const points = [
  {
    x: '30px',
    y: '50px',
data: 'Targeting Lasers',
    
  },
  {
    x: '460px',
    y: '210px',
    data: 'Targeting Lasers'
  },
  {
    x: '250px',
    y: '350px',
    data: 'Sheild Generators'
  },
  {
    x: '3890px',
    y: '550px',
    data: 'Sensor Array'
  }
];

points.forEach((point) => {
  let img = document.createElement('img'); 
  img.style.left = point.x;
  img.style.top = point.y;
  img.title = point.data;
  img.className= 'overlay-image';
  img.src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/544303/Target_Logo.svg"
  overlay.appendChild(img);
  img.data = point.data;
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
});

function handleMouseEnter(event) {
  dataField.innerHTML = event.currentTarget.data;
}


function handleMouseLeave(event) {
  dataField.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
}
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you a lot for your attention

Comment: Could you clarify: do you want to change the background color or you want to have image on the background of the box on the right?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to have an image. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add more data and assign each data object to the images. The following will change the background image when hovering the hotspot.

```
const overlay = document.querySelector('.image-overlay');
const dataField = document.querySelector('.data');

const points = [
  {
    x: '320px',
    y: '50px',
    data: {
      title: 'Extended Cockpit',
      image: "url('https://dummyimage.com/320x320/ff0000/fff')",
    }
  },
  {
    x: '460px',
    y: '210px',
    data: {
      title: 'Targeting Lasers',
      image: "url('https://dummyimage.com/320x320/00ff00/fff')",
    }
  },
  {
    x: '250px',
    y: '350px',
    data: {
      title: 'Sheild Generators',
      image: "url('https://dummyimage.com/320x320/0000ff/fff')",
    }  
  },
  {
    x: '3890px',
    y: '550px',
    data: {
      title: 'Sensor Array',
      image: "url('https://dummyimage.com/320x320/000000/fff')",
    }
  }
];

points.forEach((point) => {
  let img = document.createElement('img'); 
  img.style.left = point.x;
  img.style.top = point.y;
  img.title = point.data.title;
  img.className= 'overlay-image';
  img.src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/544303/Target_Logo.svg"
  overlay.appendChild(img);
  // Sets title and image data attributes
  img.data = point.data;
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
});

function handleMouseEnter(event) {
  // Set title and background image based on data set in target
  dataField.innerHTML = event.currentTarget.data.title;
  dataField.style.backgroundImage = event.currentTarget.data.image;
}

function handleMouseLeave(event) {
  // Reset
  dataField.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  dataField.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
}
```

Comment: but if if I'll use something like this doesn't work 

{
    x: '460px',
    y: '210px',
    data: {
      title: 'Targeting Lasers',
      bgr: 'images/myimage.jpg',
    }

How can I insert an image? Thank you so much

Comment: I would like to attribute an background image to my div depending on which hotspot is hovering

Comment: I made an update, the above sets the background image when you hover over the different hotspots.